# xcode build After showing black screen on device and simulator

Tags: ios

I have added OneSignal Plugin to My Ionic project But Project is not showing on device and simulator, it shows a black screen.

> ERROR: Error! iOS Simulator does not support push! Please test on a real iOS 
>    device. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote 
>    notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo= 
>    {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the 
>    simulator}
>
> ERROR: Error! iOS Simulator does not support push! Please test on a real iOS 
>    device. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "remote 
>    notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo= 
>    {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the 
>    simulator}`

Comment: It pretty much says it. You cannot test push notifications on the simulator.

Comment: yaaa

but its not working on real deivce

Comment: **while installing on device also it not working it's still showing black screen on my device**

Comment: i think its a problem with your initial viewController, either its not set properly or your navigationController dont have a viewController with a relationship as root.

Comment: @HanojB please share the error you're hitting when running on device

Comment: @HanojB could you share your index.html file too?